# Some issue with bufferedReader

Tags: java, function, bufferedreader

I have a java function as follows:

```
 public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> embedWords(BufferedReader buffR1 {              
   ArrayList<String > arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
   arrayList = getWords(buffR1);
   System.out.println("Word size:"+ arrayList.size());

       ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> arrList = getWordFeature(buffR1);
   System.out.println("Size of arrList:embedWords:"+arrList.size());
     }
```

Here , the problem is , the both of the function  `getWords`  and  `getWordFeatures` can't give the size value. When i comment  function `getWords` the function `getWordFeature` returns non-zero value .But when uncommented , the output is as follows:

```
Word size:15055
Size of arrList:embedWords: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

So you basically tell us, that `BufferedReader` will "eat" your input and that, once digested, there is no "read it again"?

Well, this is not surprising, since streams and readers are designed like this.

Comment: How would I overcome this situation?

Comment: You could do whatever `getWords()` and `getWordFeature()` are doing in a single method, reading the input once.

Comment: Or, if `getWords` just reads and splits the reader into words, you could rewrite `getWordFeature(Reader r)` into `getWordFeature(List<String> words)`.

Comment: Read the text first, then throw away the `BufferedReader` and use `getWords` and `getWordFeature` on the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `getWords` function has already read the contents of the `buffR1` stream by the time `getWordFeature` function is called. You will need to read the contents of the stream before calling them to avoid it.

You might want first read the contents into an array, let's call it `barr`.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int c;
while ((c = buffR1.read()) != -1) {
  bout.write(c);
}
byte[] barr = bout.toByteArray();
```

And then calling the functions using a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) with the contents of `barr`.

```
getWords(new ByteArrayInputStream(barr));
getWordFeature(new ByteArrayInputStream(barr));
```

I think this is the best solution if you can not change/refactor the methods. This solution gets pretty cool if you implement it properly as a class.